# Is "newValueHandler" of ag-grid deprecated? I can't find it in the documentation

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I was reading on `newValueHandler` from GitHub and StackOverflow questions. But I can't seem to find any documentation of it in the `ag-grid` site. Google search gives this link (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-handlers/) when I search for `newValueHandler` but its totally blank.

So, is `newValueHandler` deprecated? Is it still safe to use this or should I move to something else? Thanks

**Note** I am using the latest version of ag-grid with Angular 9

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the latest version of ag-grid (23.1.0), and the method is there.
It may not be in the online documentation, but it's still in the source of the ColDef class.

Here's a copy of the method signature with documentation from ColDef.d.ts:

```
/** Callbacks for editing. See editing section for further details.
 * Return true if the update was successful, or false if not.
 * If false, then skips the UI refresh and no events are emitted.
 * Return false if the values are the same (ie no update). */
newValueHandler?: (params: any) => boolean;
```

So, it's not marked as deprecated, and I would assume that it is safe to use.

Comment: I suppose you're correct. I was concerned to not find it in the official doc. But ag-grid team would've marked this as deprecated if it was indeed deprecated.

Comment: I have to say, I think ag-grid is a really good piece of software, but the documentation leaves a lot to be desired. I have had to reverse engineer it a number of times.

Answer (score 2):

An example newValueHandler would look like this (working on ag-grid 23.1.0):

```
column.newValueHandler = (params: { node: RowNode, data: any, oldValue: any, newValue: any, rowIndex: any, colDef: any, context: any, api: GridApi }) => {
    const validation = doYourValidationHere(.....);
    if (validationIsSuccesFull) {
        // save value in your row
       params.data[column.field] = params.newValue;
    } else {
        // not succesfull, doing nothing will automatically discard the input (do nothing)
    }
};
```

[Source](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1260#issuecomment-260876915)

Comment: I also use it like the example you provided. I was concerned that it might be deprecated as I couldn't find it in the official docs. But it seems it's not deprecated

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `newValueHandler` has been removed. I haven't found it in the [changelog](https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/), but it must happened sometime between 23.x and 29.x.

But the new `colDef` property `valueSetter` behaves exactly like the old `newValueHandler` property, as shown in the [docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20230322190849/https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/value-setters/) (I linked to an archived version since the ag-grid documentation has no versioning).